# Service that just won't die

Tags: android, service, sensors

I finally have my Services running well.  They are generating events and Broadcasting using managers.  My receiving activity even receives the broadcasts well. I have one final problem though.  I have two Services.  When I call the onDestroy() only one of them is stopping.  THe other one continues to broadcast.  It also continues to Listen for changes.  THat Service is a LightSensor that monitors for Lux events.  In my Receiving Activity when I call

```
stopService(new Intent(this, LightSensor.class));
```

The  onDestroy actually fires.  I know this because I have a Log.d event to show me that it was fired BUT it doesn't die.  The SensorListener is suposed to deregister and the  Service is suposed to stop, but even after I exit the app, it is receiving from the LightSensor.

Could someone take a look and see why this Service will not die plesae?

LightSensor

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy");
        stopSelf();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, LightSensor);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if super.onDestroy() is being called? there is a possiblity that unregisterListener is failing

Comment: Line 3 shows in the LogCat, so I am assuming the onDestroy is called. It would make sense that unreg is failing and would explain the problem.  I wonder if I put another log.d after it, if that will get me some clues.....

Comment: OK it might be dumb but I added a Log.d after each line to see if they get fired.  I can see a log entry all the way after the super.onDestroy.  If the unreg was failing, wouldn't it halt or something?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `stopSelf()` in `onDestroy()`, as it is not needed and may be harmful.

Beyond that, you need to make sure that the listener instance you pass into `unregisterListener()` is the same listener instance that you used with `registerListener()`.

Comment: // Test to see if Light Sensor is available
  if (LightSensor != null) {
   mSensorManager.registerListener(this, LightSensor,
     SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

Comment: That is the original Listener.  I do not know if it is a valid fix or not, but simply added a boolean and an if statement to start and stop the listener and the broadcasts